# Requirements for titanium app to support 64 bit

Tags: titanium

How can the earlier created 32 bit titanium app be converted into 64 bit app,what are the requirements for the titanium app to have 64 bit support??

Comment: you can follow [this blog](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2015/01/titanium-sdk-3-5-0-ga-now-available-with-64-bit-ios-support/) from titanium.

Answer (score 1):

Titanium iOS apps need to be 64 bit for a first upload by now as standard or if it's pre existing in the App store this won't have to be done till June 1st.

First make sure you are compiling your apps for Titanium 3.5.0 or greater. Download this and then rebuild your app against this.

Next you'll need to make sure all included architectures are 64 bit.

You can check any pre existing included modules comply or if they need updating via this handy NPM cli tool - Usage and how to install are included on this page.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ti-64

This will then list any modules that need updating. You have two options here, wait for the author to update them for the change or be pro active and compile the module to be 64 bit yourself.

If you open up the module in xCode you can specify a new architecture to build for and compile it again.

This article covers all update needs: 
http://www.tidev.io/2015/01/09/how-to-update-your-app-and-modules-for-64-bit-support/

Comment: I have created earlier titanium 32 bit app on titanium version 3.2.2,but now Apple's new requirement of 64 bit support, I updated my titanium sdk to 3.5.0,I have implemented no module in my earlier 32 bit titanium app.I only want to know that if I updated my titanium to Titanium SDK 3.5.0,then I generated .ipa file after updating titanium sdk,If I upload this new .ipa file on appstore,then will it be accepted,I mean ,it will not give "Missing 64 bit support"..???

Comment: My 32 bit titanium app has been uploaded to itunesconnect ,but its showing waiting review only,but the client said to convert it into 64 bit .